# Understanding c++ template code used in Webkit

Tags: c++, templates, webkit

I am looking http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/parser/Lexer.h and http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/parser/Lexer.cpp
In the header at line 196, there is a piece of code

```
template <bool shouldBuildIdentifiers> ALWAYS_INLINE JSTokenType parseIdentifier(JSTokenData*, unsigned lexerFlags, bool strictMode);
```

I can see an *implementation* of this in the cpp file as

```
template <>
template <bool shouldCreateIdentifier> ALWAYS_INLINE JSTokenType Lexer<LChar>::parseIdentifier(JSTokenData* tokenData, unsigned lexerFlags, bool strictMode)
```

My understanding of the syntax is that we are defining/specialising the function for a Lexer of type LChar. Is this correct? 
I read ([Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)) that this should ideally be done in a header file.

Also do old C++ compilers support this syntax? Mine is mips-linux-g++ v 4.1.0. I am getting a " template-id  does not match any template declaration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The bool is still allowed to vary on the method's template, and the specialization is for the class.

Though generally templates are specialised and implemented in a header file, an alternative is to add a forward declaration for the specialization, and the compiler will find it. The implementation must be linked from another file however, just like any other function with a separate declaration and definition. This has the downside that inlining won't happen without link time optimisation, but has the upside that much less code needs to be parsed whenever the template is used. On big projects this can have improve compile times significantly.

In this instance, the class's implementers have decided that there are only really two ways this class will ever be instantiated, with LChar and UChar (see the comment on line 1930). Therefore, they can put their implementations in the .cpp file, and by instantiating both templates at the bottom of the file, everything is resolved at that stage.

Templates can be used to implement completely generic classes (like `std::vector`) that expect anything, but can also be used in the place of a virtual method when you think it's very unlikely you will need more than a handful of implementations to still benefit from code reuse.

As for g++ 4.1.0, I just checked and saw it's nearly 9 years old! [So many bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&cf_known_to_fail_type=allwords&cf_known_to_work_type=allwords&query_format=advanced&resolution=FIXED&short_desc=template&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&target_milestone=4.1.1&target_milestone=4.1.2&target_milestone=4.1.3&target_milestone=4.1.4&target_milestone=4.2.0&target_milestone=4.2.1&target_milestone=4.2.2&target_milestone=4.2.3&target_milestone=4.2.4&target_milestone=4.2.5&target_milestone=4.2.6&target_milestone=4.3.0&target_milestone=4.3.1&target_milestone=4.3.2&target_milestone=4.3.3&target_milestone=4.3.4&target_milestone=4.3.5&target_milestone=4.3.6&target_milestone=4.3.7&target_milestone=4.4.0&target_milestone=4.4.1&target_milestone=4.4.2&target_milestone=4.4.3&target_milestone=4.4.4&target_milestone=4.4.5&target_milestone=4.4.6&target_milestone=4.4.7&target_milestone=4.4.8&target_milestone=4.5.0&target_milestone=4.5.1&target_milestone=4.5.2&target_milestone=4.5.3&target_milestone=4.5.4&target_milestone=4.5.5&target_milestone=4.6.0&target_milestone=4.6.1&target_milestone=4.6.2&target_milestone=4.6.3&target_milestone=4.6.4&target_milestone=4.6.5&target_milestone=4.7.0&target_milestone=4.7.1&target_milestone=4.7.2&target_milestone=4.7.3&target_milestone=4.7.4&target_milestone=4.7.5&target_milestone=4.8.0&target_milestone=4.8.1&target_milestone=4.8.2&target_milestone=4.8.3&target_milestone=4.8.4&target_milestone=4.8.5&target_milestone=4.9.0&target_milestone=4.9.1&target_milestone=4.9.2) relating to templates have been fixed since then that if you are doing anything non-trivial with them, it's really worth trying to upgrade.

Comment: "The bool is still allowed to vary on the method's template, and the specialization is for the class." What does this mean? Is the return type a bool?

Comment: In this case there are in total two template parameters. One applies to the class (the `T` in `template <typename T> class Lexer`), and the second is on the method (the `bool shouldCreateIdentifier`). We are setting `T` to be `LChar`, but we are still letting `shouldCreateIdentifier` take different values. This is also known as a partial specialization.

Comment: Does this mean that there can be some type other than bool for shouldCreateIdentifier?

Comment: No, it has to be a `bool`. Template parameters can either be a typename, or an integral type / enum. There are some other rarely used ones, [see 14.1.4 and 14.1.5 of the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) for the gory details). Here, `bool` is actually an integral type, and the only values allowed are `true` and `false`. Another place you will more commonly see an integral template paramater would be `std::array`

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html  gives details about compiler support for C++ features